# Typescript conditional inheritance

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js

The goal is to create a prototype which can extends different classes.
I need to create a class that extends either Mesh or Points of THREE.js. The subclass I made is the same for either of these cases. It cannot be interface.

```
class PointsElement extends THREE.Points {
  public name: string
  protected width: number
  protected height: number

  constructor (protected target: THREE.Scene | THREE.Group, protected properties: IElementProperties) {
    super()
    this.name = this.properties.name
    AutoBind(this)
  }

  public async preload () {
  }

  public async show () {
    this.target.add(this)
  }

  public async hide () {
    this.target.remove(this)
  }
}

class MeshElement extends THREE.Mesh {
  public name: string
  protected width: number
  protected height: number

  constructor (protected target: THREE.Scene | THREE.Group, protected properties: IElementProperties) {
    super()
    this.name = this.properties.name
    AutoBind(this)
  }

  public async preload () {
  }

  public async show () {
    this.target.add(this)
  }

  public async hide () {
    this.target.remove(this)
  }
}
```

What I want to do is to reduce the code by exclude the 'Element', as the  body is the same in MeshElement and PointsElement, but each of these class extends different classes

Comment: Conditional inheritance is universally addressed as the Factory Pattern

Comment: Factory pattern would be helpful if I had to return new Mesh or Points with additional arguments. I need to create classes with properties of element and either Mesh or Points. Like 'class MeshElement extends THREE.Mesh { ...Element.prototype }' and 'class PoinstElement extends THREE.Points { ...Element.prototype }'.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little quick and dirty but hopefully you get the idea as to what I mean by a factory pattern.

What you described is only 1 way of doing factory not the only.

```
enum Geometrics {
  Mesh = "Mesh",
  Points = "Points"
}

class Element {
  public isElement = true;
}

class Mesh extends Element {
  public type = Geometrics.Mesh;
}

class Point extends Element {
  public type = Geometrics.Points;
}

class GeometricsFactory<T extends Geometrics> {
  private shapesMap = new Map<Geometrics, typeof Mesh | typeof Point>([
    [Geometrics.Mesh, class Shape extends Mesh {}],
    [Geometrics.Points, class Shape extends Point {}]
  ]);

  constructor(private type: Geometrics) {}

  public getShape(): T extends Geometrics.Mesh ? typeof Mesh : typeof Point {
    const shape = this.shapesMap.get(this.type);
    if (shape) {
      return <T extends Geometrics.Mesh ? typeof Mesh : typeof Point>shape;
    }
    throw new Error(`Invalid shape type ${this.type}`);
  }
}

const MyMesh = new (new GeometricsFactory<Geometrics.Mesh>(Geometrics.Mesh).getShape())();
console.log(MyMesh.type);

const MyPoints = new (new GeometricsFactory<Geometrics.Points>(Geometrics.Points).getShape())();
console.log(MyPoints.type);
```

Comment: The `THREE.Mesh` class already comes with [its own properties and methods](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Mesh), and so does [`THREE.Points`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Points). Would these be inherited with the approach outlined above?

Comment: In this case I can get class Shape which extends Mesh or Points, but I can't predefine what exactly is the 'shape'. In my case I have to create Shape class, and then decide which class I want to extend. I'll edit the question to make it more understandable.

Comment: Add more classes earlier. Shape is just a last return

Comment: @AliHabibzadeh I can't really understand what do you mean... Could you please turn my example into factory?